Pods Installing in Kony Symbol not found:
when I am to install XYZ framework form cocoa pods in iOS native projects it's working fine but when I am trying to install same XYZ framework in Kony Using cocoa pods it's giving runtime erorr:
dyld[1341]: Symbol not found: __ZN5swift34swift50override_conformsToProtocolEPKNS_14TargetMetadataINS_9InProcessEEEPKNS_24TargetProtocolDescriptorIS1_EEPFPKNS_18TargetWitnessTableIS1_EES4_S8_E
  Referenced from: <CE033968-7073-3D1A-8A36-6BBF2A3E9C95> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F975C8B5-5374-4C3A-A6CA-1639DC7D65D6/Vyom.app/Frameworks/XYZSDK.framework/XYZSDK
  Expected in:     <A66B9E98-B340-36D4-903E-71441114E8C4> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F975C8B5-5374-4C3A-A6CA-1639DC7D65D6/Vyom.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON


I have Tried Below Things:

I have tried installing pod using pod install
I have directly drag and drag XYZSDK in project and added SwiftyJSON as swift package manager

